Setting up multiple environments (test, accept, production) on 1 server
I want to verify if this is a good approach:
I am thinking of deploying test, accept and production on the same server:
I think it can be done like this:

create separate databases for test, accept and production
checkout repos for custom modules out in separate directories module_test, module_accept, module_prod. In these directorys checkout the correct branches (like test, accept and main)
Install the correct module for all the environments: module_test in test, etc.
connect the test, accept and prod url's to the correct datbase, using dbfilter in odoo-conf

Is this a sensible approach or is it better to use separate vm's for all environments?

Bad idea. The purpose of a test system is also to be able to test upgrades of the environment (os, db server, ...) which your setup won't allow. Furthermore when you for instance  stress test it will have drawbacks on the production system. And finally, when you test environment causes some catastrophic failure, it could also destroy your production system. I'd suggest to put production as far away from test as possible.

One system for all environments:
Example: The productive environment uses an os package with version 1.0  and the test environment uses version 1.2
Then it must be possible to install both versions on the same system.
Using different VMs do not have this problem.

Using VMs although allows the change of the OS itself (e.g. debian-bullseye to debian-bookworm)
